# Convert 20200324003032 to date and tim

Tags: sql, type-conversion

Can someone help with splitting this value 20200324003032

Into a date and time so it should display 24-03-2020 00:30:32

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's your flavor of database? Date related stuff often isn't quite doable with strictly ANSI Standard Sql.

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Is that value held as a numeric or text value?

Answer (score 1):

**MS Sql Server**

In MS Sql Server the first 8 digits can be cast to a datetime.

And the last 6 digits can be stuffed, then casted to a datetime.

Adding the 2 together will create a datetime that has both the date & time.  Which can then be converted to the ODBC datetime format.

> ```
> select *
> , try_convert(varchar(19), 
>     cast(left(datetime_number,8) as datetime) +
>     cast(stuff(stuff(right(datetime_number,6),5,0,':'),3,0,':') as datetime)
>     , 120) as datetime_stamp
> from (values 
>   (20200324003032)
> , (cast(format(getdate(), 'yyyyMMddHHmmss') as decimal(14))) 
> ) test(datetime_number)
> ```

| datetime_number | datetime_stamp |
| --- | --- |
| 20200324003032 | 2020-03-24 00:30:32 |
| 20220111172840 | 2022-01-11 17:28:40 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a026d3e7bd0047093fb61ccb3100c334)*

**PostgreSQL**

In PostgreSQL it's a bit easier.
Since it just requires an extra space to cast it to a timestamp.

> ```
> select *
> , regexp_replace(datetime_number::text,'^(\d{8})(\d{6})$','\1 \2')::timestamp as ts
> from (values 
>   (20200324003032)
> , (to_char('now'::timestamp, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')::bigint)
> ) test(datetime_number);
> ```

| datetime_number | ts |
| --- | --- |
| 20200324003032 | 2020-03-24 00:30:32 |
| 20220111173248 | 2022-01-11 17:32:48 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=b3f39e9c05a2baf696ad977310481792)*

**MySql**

It's really simple in MySql.

> ```
> select *
> , timestamp(datetime_number)  as ts
> from ( 
>   select 20200324003032 as datetime_number
>   union all select now()+0
> ) test;
> ```

| datetime_number | ts |
| --- | --- |
| 20200324003032 | 2020-03-24 00:30:32 |
| 20220111181558 | 2022-01-11 18:15:58 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=2766cd0e514714579a786ed8520faf54)*

Comment: Brilliant Thank you

Comment: So for which database system did you need this?